# SQL Server : Pathname of stored tables

Tags: sql-server

What is the pathname where tables are stored in, please ?

> Cannot drop the table 'dbo.Superviseur', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I've got this error, so I thought that I may try to delete that table manually.

Comment: All tables of a given SQL Server database are stored in one of the one or multiple **data files** - but you should ***NOT*** be fiddling around with those files directly! Let SQL Server handle those pesky details for you!

Comment: You can screw up multiple databases by deleting one device.

Answer (score 0):

> delete that table manually.

That's now how a big database server like SQL Server works. What you did *was* "delete it manually". The error message was pretty descriptive. Either it's not in the database you're connected to, or your account doesn't have permission. Satisfy those prerequisites, and the table can be dropped.

Comment: no, I've deleted that table using GUI of SQL Server, I'm working in localhost, after this mistake I have this error message when I try to update my database using Package Management Console !

Comment: You should add that information to your question then, as it becomes a Package Management Console issue.